# Do all transmembrane proteins contain channels or tunnels?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane, protein-structure

In my book, there is written something like this.
The integral proteins pass into the lipid bilayer to different depths and establish hydrophobic bonds with lipid molecules. **Some of the integral proteins run throughout the lipid bilayer.** They are called *tunnel proteins* **OR** *transmembrane proteins.*
My question is do all the transmembrane proteins have to have channel or tunnel for transport of materials?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26878/ Might help dude. Anyway it is quite easy to find something about it and if you dont do a little searching about it nobody will have attempt to answer it.

Comment: You know idk what you mean by the material stuff but i think the right answer is just no !

Comment: The substances .

Comment: What could it be other than this?

Comment: I was asking if all the transmembrane proteins have to be tunnel proteins as it was written in my book . And I think that's not right .

Comment: When you search Pubmed for "transmembrane proteins" you get 78328 hits.  "Tunnel protein" gets 2312.

Comment: @swbarnes2 that doesn't mean that they aren't interchangeable terms. For example, polytopic proteins and multi-pass proteins might return different numbers but mean the same thing. There is a lot of redundant jargon in this field!

Comment: It doesn't mean that they are.  When I checked a few of the abstracts in the pubmed search, they were mostly about the "exit tunnel" of the bacterial ribosome.  None were about transmembrane proteins.

Comment: @swbarnes2 I must say, I haven't read anything that suggests tunnel proteins and transmembrane proteins are interchangeable terms.

Answer (score 4):

## Transmembrane proteins don't all have tunnels.

> Do all the transmembrane proteins have to have channel or tunnel for transport of materials?

Calling transmembrane proteins tunnel proteins is very misleading. There are a wide range of functions carried out by transmembrane proteins. I'd say the most famous example that don't include a tunnel are the [GPCRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_protein%E2%80%93coupled_receptor) that have 7 transmembrane segments. These are used for passing information across a membrane by acting as a receptor to a molecule on one side causing a conformational change which causes an action on the other side of the membrane.

## How many transmembrane proteins do have tunnels?

[Here is a link to all the GO annotation held by UniProt](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=annotation%3A%28type%3Atransmem%29&sort=score#goViewBy) on transmembrane proteins. There are 10s of millions of results including, but certainly not limited to tunnels and channels.

In the human proteome, there are 831 transmembrane proteins tagged with G-PCR (7TM proteins without a tunnel). 
The "Transport" keyword, which probably has some sort of tunnel, is present in 1106 transmembrane proteins. 
In total there are around 5200 human transmembrane proteins in the human proteome.